# Rendering ExtJS 4+ MVC application in a html div - how-to?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, extjs-mvc, extjs4.2

All examples that I have found so far explain how to render ExtJS (4.2) MVC application within the "viewport", which in other words means full browser screen, and occupying whole HTML BODY.

I would like to render application within the existing HTML page within named DIV, so that I can have HTML design around the application.

```
 <div id="appdiv"><!-- application runs here --></div>
```

I've seen some sites with ExtJS 4 examples that use trick to render ExtJS app within the page by using IFRAME.

Is it possible to avoid IFRAME? And, if it is, how skeleton of ExtJS 4.2 application shall look like if it will be rendered within a div.

Notes: In ExtJS 3 I have found the solution by creating a panel as main container which renders within named div. However, version 4.2 (and possibly earlier 4.x's) suggests MVC application approach that seem far superior.

---- Edits

I have realised that I have to put starting points for this question.

1. Source for this example is generated by ExtJS's CMD command that generates "application" framework skeleton.
2. Skeleton of application is consisted of many files including engine reference, and other references, so I would not be able to include here all sources in "application" dir/folder. Skeleton of application can be done using cmd in the fashion: `sencha -sdk /myuserroot/Sencha/Cmd/3.1.1.274 generate app ExtGenApp /mywebroot/htdocs/extja_genapp` This generates files and folders and copies all necessary files in the place.
3. "User" activity area is in "app" dir. App dir has subdirs for views, controllers, models and additional stuff.
4. As in many other frameworks you are expected to keep folder structure so that framework can find appropriate files and initialise them.
5. list of files:

index.html (in the root of the generated application)

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>ExtGenApp</title>
        <!-- <x-compile> -->
            <!-- <x-bootstrap> -->
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.css">
                <script src="ext/ext-dev.js"></script>
                <script src="bootstrap.js"></script>
            <!-- </x-bootstrap> -->
            <script src="app/app.js"></script>
        <!-- </x-compile> -->
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>HTML Before</h1>
        <div id="appBox"></div>
        <h1>HTML After</h1>
    </body>
    </html>
```

app/app.js

```
    /*
        This file is generated and updated by Sencha Cmd. You can edit this file as
        needed for your application, but these edits will have to be merged by
        Sencha Cmd when it performs code generation tasks such as generating new
        models, controllers or views and when running "sencha app upgrade".

        Ideally changes to this file would be limited and most work would be done
        in other places (such as Controllers). If Sencha Cmd cannot merge your
        changes and its generated code, it will produce a "merge conflict" that you
        will need to resolve manually.
    */

    // DO NOT DELETE - this directive is required for Sencha Cmd packages to work.
    //@require @packageOverrides



    Ext.application({
        name: 'ExtGenApp',

        views: [
            'Main',
            'appBoxView'
        ],

        controllers: [
            'Main'
        ],

        launch: function() {
            new Ext.view.appBoxView({
                renderTo: 'appBox'
            });;  // generates error      
        }
    });
```

note: originally there is no launch function but there is auto generate viewport (one gets that by default generator)

app/controller/Main.js

```
    Ext.define('ExtGenApp.controller.Main', {
        extend: 'Ext.app.Controller'
    });
```

app/view/appBoxView.js

```
    Ext.define('ExtGenApp.view.appBoxView', {
        extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',

        requires:[
            'Ext.tab.Panel',
            'Ext.layout.container.Border'
        ],

        layout: {
            type: 'border'
        },

        items: [{
            region: 'west',
            xtype: 'panel',
            title: 'west',
            width: 150
        },{
            region: 'center',
            xtype: 'tabpanel',
            items:[{
                title: 'Center Tab 1'
            }]
        }]
    });
```

this shall be initial layout on the screen (AFAIK)

and finally:

app/view/Main.js

```
    Ext.define("ExtGenApp.view.Main", {
        extend: 'Ext.Component',
        html: 'Hello, World!!'
    });
```

which shall, as I understood, be the "content".

as is, it generates an error of not founding "Ext.view.appBoxView" and how it looks to me, framework do not initialise the application.

Comment: Re: Meredith unfortunately due to combination of doubtful ext licensing (for commercial product) and for the same time these initial hurdles the project for which this research has been tried got kicked off by another path, so, honestly I did not have much of a time in the meantime to assess answers. I plan to evaluate and close this question if this is clear enough. 
IN the same time I would ask also for guidance from admins as this question seems to be generated opinionated answers, and may reveal more interesting insights about EXT.js MVC framework maybe to remain open for a while more???

Comment: Also in the meantime I started to believe that authors of Ext.Js did not envision use of this framework in fashion I have described. Making application to run in full size of browser is out of the projects initial idea of ext.js integration into the larger system.

Comment: ??? Not sure what I said in my comment (if I ever made one last year?) but I've long since moved on from using ExtJS. I ended up using it as a full-page application framework instead of just one grid component, the way the designers intended it to be used. Some grouping plugin had a bug if the grid wasn't used in that manner.

Answer (score 3):

A viewport is just a specialized `Ext.container.Container` that auto sizes to the the document body.

As such, you can easily create your own in the launch method:

```
launch: function(){
    new MyContainer({
        renderTo: 'myDiv'
    });
}
```

Comment: yes, that's it is how this can be done in ExtJS 3. But ExtJS4 MVC app is consisted of views and auto-rendering viewport. Tried this and it tells me that MyContainer is not defined, how I can reference it to a 'view"?

Comment: Auto rendering of the viewport basically does exactly what I have above. Declare your own view `MyApp.view.Container` in the same way you'd declare a viewport. Require it in your views, then create it as I suggested above.

Comment: still could not figure out how to instantiate main container but since views are defined elsewhere it looks to me that I shall use Ext.Create method in launch, there is some discussion here http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?127671-Ext.create-vs-the-keyword-new but still no working recipe.

Comment: The only difference between create/new is that create will lookup any outstanding dependencies, new will not. I'm not really sure how to explain any further, in launch you create an instance of your container component.

Comment: Will compile a set of sources in an attempt answer, seeing no other way of explaining where problem may be. It fails somewhere between "framework" and definitions.

Answer (score 1):

In some of these answers, some suggest using an Ext.Panel with a renderTo.  You shouldn't be using an Ext.Panel if you're not going to be utilizing it for anything other than a container if you're going to go this route.  You should be using Ext.container.Container instead.

By using Ext.Panel you are adding a bunch of unnecessary things like the title bar and such to your component. Each one of these puts extra place holders there even if you aren't using them.

Answer (score 1):

I liked Evan Trimboli's concise approach but I could not get it to work either (it also told me that MyContainer is not defined).  However this approach worked...

```
launch: function () {    
    Ext.create('widget.MyContainer', {
        renderTo: 'MyDiv'
    });
}
```

...where `'widget.MyContainer'` is the alias created inside the view itself, and provided I also did this up top:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.Application', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Application',

    name: 'MyApp',

    views: [
        'MyApp.view.MyContainer'
    ],
...
```

Comment: `MyContainer` was just a name I made up, there's no built in class called that.

Comment: Right, I had created the class (just as I did for my example above). But even when doing that and referencing it in the Application, I could not seem to do `new MyContainer` without without it saying 'not defined'. Is there something I missed?

Comment: Your class is `MyApp.view.MyContainer`.

Comment: Interesting.  I was assuming it would see/use the alias.  So using this approach, I see it does not require an inclusion under "views" up above.  Bottom line, there are several ways to instantiate.  But is there one you would suggest as best practice?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using Ext.panel.Panel or Ext.window.Window as a container?

```
<div id="appBox">
<script type="text/javascript">  

Ext.require('Ext.panel.Panel');
        Ext.onReady(function(){

            Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
                renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
                width: 400,
                height: 300,
                title: 'Container Panel',
                items: [
                    {
                        xtype: 'panel',
                        title: 'Child Panel 1',
                        height: 100,
                        width: '75%'
                    },
                    {
                        xtype: 'panel',
                        title: 'Child Panel 2',
                        height: 100,
                        width: '75%'
                    }
                ]
            });


        })

    </script>
</div>
```